# What is a $(p,q)$-tensor field, really?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

In the Frederic Schuller lectures, a $(p,q)$-tensor field is defined as a map that takes $p$ copies of $\Gamma(T^*M)$ and $q$ copies of $\Gamma(TM)$, and maps them multilinearly to a scalar in the underlying field.

I honestly would have preferred to define it as the section of a tensor bundle. Smoothness of the tensor field feels a lot simpler to understand in this second case. I'm guessing both approaches are identical anyways, but when would you use one over the other?

Comment: It is a section of $(T^*M)^{\otimes ^p}\otimes (TM)^{\otimes q}$ (or the converse)

Comment: The approach in the 1st paragraph is preferable if students in the class (or reader of the book) are unfamiliar with the formalism of vector bundles and/or tensor products. Otherwise, the 2nd approach is better.

Comment: These are equivalent descriptions in the $C^{\infty}$ case. Conceptually, I prefer the second definition as a section of the $(p,q)$ tensor bundle $T^p_q(TM):= (TM)^{\otimes p}\otimes (T^*M)^{\otimes q}$, but some times, the first method is more convenient for quickly defining tensor fields. See my remarks in [Why is the Riemann tensor $C^{\infty}$-multilinear?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/664740/203278)